# Is it possible to merge my two accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed

I am this user: https://serverfault.com/users/130303/tom (called "Tom1") When I asked my first question I wasn't registered on ServerFault (now I am). Between my first and my second question I had a problem described in my second question: [Windows XP Computer moved from domain member to workgroup member: Can I restore my old user profile?](https://serverfault.com/questions/414265/windows-xp-computer-moved-from-domain-member-to-workgroup-member-can-i-restore) resulting in a loss of my authentication cookie. (I don't know if I can ever come back as an unregistered user without cookie.) So, I asked the second question as a new user: https://serverfault.com/users/130959/tom (called "Tom2").

Unfortunely following the advice in the answer to the second question I lost the cookie of Tom2 and got back the cookie of Tom1 (the loss was expected). I registered then as Tom1. The problem is that I cannot come back as Tom2 due to the cookie loss (which is final and not recoverable this time) and Tom1 cannot accept an answer to Tom2's question because he is not Tom2, nor can Tom1 write a comment under an answer to Tom2's question because - I guess - Tom1 doesn't have enough reputation.

I am unhappy that Tom1 cannot say "thank you" to Bart Silverstrim's helpful answer, either by accepting the answer or by writing a comment.

Is it possible to move Tom2's question into Tom1's responsibility (and destroy Tom2 afterwards)?

If not, I would be very pleased if someone could write a "thank you" on behalf of me under Bart Silverstrim's answer. Also please notify him that Tom1 did upvote his answer as a little, yet imperfect substitute for accepting the answer and that his proposal worked (although I still have trouble with a lot if applications, but this is definitely not the fault of his solution). Also I'd like to announce officially that I hereby accept his answer and ask a moderator/superuser to put a green check mark to Bart Silverstrim's deserved benefit.

Comment: No problem, should be done soonish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User merges are something moderators can do, and for reasons like yours (unregistered users becoming registered) are very much encouraged. I've just merged the two accounts so you should be able to rectify the situation.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I could accept the answer of Tom2's question. BTW: Did I something wrong with my second question that is the reason for the downvotes? I had read the Faq before I asked to be sure if the question does belong here at all and checked for duplicate questions. I honestly had the feeling it's the right place and nobody wrote a comment what I did wrong.

Comment: @Tom That probably earned downvotes from seeming too end-user like which explains the 3 migration votes to SuperUser. "My profile" is personal, "one of my user's profile" is more professional.

Comment: Aaaah, now I understand. I didn't know the SuperUser site, will consider this next time. I actually have noticed in the Faq that ServerFault is for "professionals". I'm probably a border case: The PC I have the problems with is my corporate PC, the domain my company's domain, the workgroup my company's workgroup, I have to care about our network among thousand other things (we are a very small company), accidentally I have indeed the problem with my own PC, it is Saturday and I am sitting in my office...